# Backup algorithm in Bash using dry-run

Tags: bash

This is my algorithm to backup data on Windows using Bash scripting language.
I'm looking forward to any innovations, and better solutions. My task was to create a simple backup algorithm using dry-run and delete.  Are there any simpler solutions? Also, adding a GUI would be a pretty nice training for me, but in my case, I'm not too familiar with that.

```
#!/bin/bash

src=$1
dst=$2

option1=$3
option2=$4

src_files=$(ls $src)
dst_files=$(ls $dst)

files_to_copy () {
    files_to_copy=()
    for file in $src_files; do
        if [[ ! $dst_files =~ $file ]]; then
            files_to_copy+=($file)
        fi
    done
    echo ${files_to_copy[@]}
}

files_to_delete () {
    to_delete=(  )
    for file in $dst_files; do
        if [[ ! $src_files =~ $file ]]; then
            to_delete+=($file)
        fi
    done
    echo ${to_delete[@]}
}

to_copy=$(files_to_copy)

if [[ "$option1" == "del" || "$option2" == "del" ]]; then
    to_delete=$(files_to_delete)
fi

dry_run () {
    for file in ${to_copy[@]}
    do
        echo cp $src/$file $dst
    done
    
    for file in ${to_delete[@]}
    do
        echo rm $dst/$file 
    done
}

run () {
    for file in ${to_copy[@]}
    do
        cp $src/$file $dst
    done
    
    for file in ${to_delete[@]}
    do
        rm $dst/$file 
    done
}

if [[ "$option1" == "dryrun" || "$option2" == "run" ]]; then
    dry_run
else
    run
fi
```

Thank you in advance, and have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Bash, then you can take advantage of array variables for `src_files` and `dst_files`.  Definitely don't just expand `$(ls)` like that, because the result will be word-split according to `$IFS`.

Having built a neat array in `files_to_copy()`, we then lose all its structure by printing out and storing in a string variable.

I don't think `$file` is set when `files_to_copy()` is invoked - add `set -u` to make sure we don't attempt to use non-existent variables.

Instead of separate `run` and `dry_run`, we can use a variable to selectively enable 'echo' like this:

```
run()
{
    ${prefix+"${prefix[@]}"} cp "${to_copy[@]/#/$src/}" "$dst"
    ${prefix+"${prefix[@]}"} rm "${to_delete[@]/#/$dst/}"
}

dry_run()
{
    prefix=(echo) do_it "$@"
}
```

(I also simplified your loops into single commands, by substituting the directory at start of each filename, which works only if `to_copy` and `to_delete` are actually arrays of filenames).

Comment: Hii, when i was trying to use your run() function i'm getting errors
"cp: cannot stat '/backupv1.sh understanding_swap.sh whiptail.sh': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'backup/': Is a directory"

Comment: Yes.  As I said that will only work once `to_copy` and `to_delete` are correctly populated as arrays of filenames.  I perhaps should have made that condition more prominent!